# Best approach to load a PDF in canvas

Tags: pdf, html5-canvas, pdf.js

Here, I have tried a various approach for loading a PDF to the canvas. First thing is I used the library PDF.JS to load the PDF in canvas. The problem I faced with PDF.JS is that when I try to zoom in to the PDF - [
I tried two approaches

1. Zooming in to the object and the canvas - which made browser crash in a certain point in scaling
2. Converting the image as a object and loading it to canvas using Fabric JS and zooming in to the object - which made the pixel to break while zooming in (scaling was not proper to a certain point while zooming in)]

So, suggest me some best way to upload a PDF in canvas with perfect scaling while zooming in without any crash to the browser when I upload some bigger size PDF.

Thanks In advance! :)

Comment: If you are determined to stick with PDF.js, which apparently cannot handle your PDF, then you might want to look at repair/simplify/optimize your PDF offline beforehand. Otherwise, you could look at "fixing" PDF.js (since it is open source), or looking at another client side javascript PDF viewer, to see if they can handle your PDF better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ryan. Can you suggest me some optimized open source PDF Viewer?

Comment: By open source, I assume you actually mean open source and no-cost. No just PDF.js. You would have to look at paid commercial solutions if you want a better PDF viewer.